# Optimal Splitting of Feature-Target Pairs within Input Size Constraints

Tags: algorithm, optimization, processing-efficiency, chunking

I'm dealing with two lists—one comprising features and the other containing targets. The task at hand involves processing all possible feature-target pairs. Ideally, I'd combine these two lists into a single input for processing. However, due to an input size constraint, I'm required to split them and merge the outputs afterward. I experimented with taking all the features in all the chunks and adding as many unprocessed targets as possible to each chunk. Unfortunately, this approach doesn't accommodate scenarios where the features alone surpass the input size constraint.

Is there an algorithm or an optimized approach that can intelligently split these feature-target pairs, ensuring eventual processing of all pairs while minimizing the number of required calls?